# .htaccess redirect too many times?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have written a rule for redirect in .htaccess but it redirects too many times and breaks the page

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /consultation/first_t [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(http://babycareadvice.com)? /consultation/first_time? [R=301]
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Condition pattern and Rule's target are identical and that is why you are getting multiple redirects . To fix this, just replace your RewriteCond with this

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /consultation/first_t\s [NC]
```